# How to parse Youtube search results?

Tags: python

When a user submits a query, I would like to append this to search results in Youtube and download this "page" on the backend of my code (Python-Django).

What is the best way to do this? 
Do you suggest that I do this manually? And create a custom parser? Scanning each line for a certain pattern...

Or is there an easier way, such as using their API?

By the way, I am familiar with crawling.  I just want to know the method for YOUTUBE.  I understand how to download/parse pages. (I will be using urllib2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred way is probably with the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api)